# Can I reduce the amount of duplicated Swift code when passing an array of tuples into a function?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I'm writing code for an introductory Swift assignment. I'm using an array of tuples as the input to a function, and I'll return an array with some of the same tuples.

With my current knowledge of Swift, I need to declare the array of tuples three times in a row. I need to declare the inputs to the function, declare what the function will return, and also declare an empty array to append values and return.

This seems fairly redundant. If I'm stuck using tuples, is there a way to rewrite this so I don't have to copy and paste code three times?

(I'm guessing the real answer will be to use something like classes, structs, or objects instead of tuples, but I'm not that far into Swift yet)

```
func findCleanAgents(agents: [(coverName: String, realName: String, accessLevel: Int, compromised: Bool)])
    -> [(coverName: String, realName: String, accessLevel: Int, compromised: Bool)] {
        var cleanAgents = [(coverName: String, realName: String, accessLevel: Int, compromised: Bool)]()
        for agent in agents {
            if agent.compromised == false {
                print("\(agent.coverName) isn't compromised.")
                cleanAgents.append(agent)
            }
        }
        return cleanAgents
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `typealias`, which is named exactly after what it does: an alias for a type:

```
typealias AgentTuple = (coverName: String, realName: String, accessLevel: Int, compromised: Bool)

func findCleanAgents(agents: [AgentTuple]) -> [AgentTuple] {
  var cleanAgents: [AgentTuple] = []
  for agent in agents {
    if agent.compromised == false {
       print("\(agent.coverName) isn't compromised.")
       cleanAgents.append(agent)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's Swift's [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID361)

Tuples are best suited for a function that returns multiple values. They are not really convenient to pass around.

In your case, if these four data types typically go together, consider creating a new type:

```
struct Agent {
  var coverName: String
  var realName: String
  var accessLevel: Int
  var compromised: Bool
}

let agent = Agent(coverName: "Arlington Beech", realName: "James Bond", ...)
```